How to create video by stacking two videos side-by-side without re-encoding?
I want to stack two 1920 x 2160 video clips side-by-side to make one 3840 x 2160 clip that can be played on my TV. The video clips are HDR.
I need to do this without re-encoding as I need to be able to compare the clips as-is to determine what difference the various parameters make, if any.

Pretty sure it is going to be impossible to do without reencoding due to resolution change. Maybe look into a way to display 2 videos next to each other using 2 different players, or the same player twice?

This question is similar to: How to play multiple videos side-by-side synchronized?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
